# How to bind DataGrid columns to inner list of selected item

Tags: xamarin.forms

**I have my list in my viewmodel:**

```
public ObservableCollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
```

**I have such property in my viewmodel:**

```
private Order _selectedOrder;
public Order SelectedOrder
{
   get => _selectedOrder;
   set => SetValue(ref _selectedOrder, value);
}
```

**Class Order contains list of items as shown below:**

```
public class Order
{
   public int OrderId { get; set; }
   public List<Item> OrderItems { get; set; }
}
```

**Item class:**

```
public class Item
{
   public int ItemId{ get; set; }
   public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

I want to bind my grid to `Orders` and based on `selected order` i would like to know how to access properties of `Item`. So `Order > OrderItems (ItemId and Name)` how can i specify it in `grid` configuration?

**This is what i have now but doesn't work (grid shows empty):**

```
<dataGrid:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}"
                         SelectionEnabled="True"
                         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOrder}"
               RowHeight="70"
                         HeaderHeight="50" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" HeaderBackground="#E0E6F8"
               PullToRefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
                         IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}">
    <dataGrid:DataGrid.Columns>
                     <dataGrid:DataGridColumn Title="Id" PropertyName="OrderItems.ItemId"/>
                     <dataGrid:DataGridColumn Title="Name" PropertyName="OrderItems.Name"/>
  </dataGrid:DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Each row is one Order.  How do you expect to display multiple OrderItems in a single column?

Comment: @Each order contains list<Item> so in grid as rows i want to see each OrderItem and cols as itemId and Name. So let's say selected item is Order X, Order X contains (list<Item>) for instance 2 are there. So at the end 2 rows

Comment: if you want each row to be one OrderItem, then your ItemsSource should be bound to OrderItems, not Orders

Comment: @Jason hmm but OrderItems is the property of Orders. If i point ItemSource as ItemsSource="{Binding OrderItems} then it will "don't know" that its inside selected Order from Orders. I also tried like that: <dataGrid:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}" SelectionEnabled="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOrder.OrderItems}". Can you post as asnwer what is the solution in this case?

Comment: you need to bind to the OrderItems property of **one specific order**.  If you have a property `SelectedOrder` in your VM, then `ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedOrder.OrderItems}"`

Comment: @Jason yes ! eh i am stupid that i didin;t tread that i couldn't see that ! Maybe you could post as answer therefore i could mark as answer. Thanks Jason. P.S I am very new to Xamarin but i like it very much of that bindings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want each row to be an `OrderItem`, then your binding should be

```
ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedOrder.OrderItems}"
```

and

```
<dataGrid:DataGridColumn Title="Id" PropertyName="ItemId"/>
<dataGrid:DataGridColumn Title="Name" PropertyName="Name"/>
```

Comment: If possible i have additional question - when i add new item to collection of SelectedOrder.OrderItems means:    SelectedOrder.OrderItems.Add(new OrderBottle.Item(55, "aaa")); and then i do: OnPropertyChanged($"SelectedOrder"); my grid is not updating. Do you have any thoughts what could be wrong?

Comment: use an ObservableCollection, not a List

Comment: you mean for OrderItems?

Comment: One last thing here. Let's imagine now user selects some item on grid. If i have button there i want to know on view model which one was selected (the id of item) - in this case i could make COmmand to the button, but is it nesacary to use xsml.cs to get this id? Otherwise i only now which selectedOrder is selected without knowing the item. Thanks

Comment: just bind `SelectedItem` to a property on your VM

Comment: Item is within SelectedOrder, so you mean create additional property anyway -SelectedItem and set it? Not sure if understood